# How can I read my circles/streams in Google-plus

Tags: javascript, google-plus

This seems like it should be really easy but I couln't find an answer anywhere. google/stackoverflow/api-site

I would like to get all posts from a specific circle from my own account. So far I can only get a single users' posts but I would like to have a json with all the posts from a specific circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [API Reference Site](https://developers.google.com/+/api/):

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

The people in your circles are not considered public data, so there is not yet an API that allows for this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

From near the top of [the G+ API homepage](https://developers.google.com/+/api/):

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

Your circles are not public data. The information you want is not currently available.

Comment: Wow.  Mindlink--second time I've been beaten to a nearly identical answer by a few seconds.

Comment: Two almost exactly the same answers. I felt pitty that I could only give one "Accept Answer". So I choose the first one I got.

Comment: Actually you chose the second one that you got, form looking at the time of the answers...